# Отличие chronyd от ntpd

Tags: linux, время, ntp

Чем принципиально отличаются `chronyd` и `ntpd`?

Конкретно интересует момент с плавной подстройкой времени. Есть мнение, что `chronyd` этого не умеет. Насколько безопасно его использовать в продакшене, особенно в сочетании с сервисами, которые довольно чувствительно относятся к путешествиям во времени (которые могут быть вызваны резким переводом часов)? К примеру MySQL сервер может не пережить резкого перевода времени на несколько секунд и упасть. Что, конечно, недопустимо в действующем проекте.

Answer (score 1):

Chronyd такое ещё как умеет! Причём по умолчанию именно такой режим и активирован. В течение работы Chronyd всегда плавно подстраивает время, если отсутствует директива [makestep](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.1/chrony.conf.html#makestep) (или указан нулевой лимит). Впрочем, можно задать число корректировок времени, в которые демон может скачкообразно изменять показания часов.